# preg_match for business letter reference number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, telegram-bot

Can you help me to build a better regex for me? I'm now making telegram bot, and it gather user input to check their proposal status. I need to validate their input with `preg_match`.

example reference number:

```
11/A-9/XI/2015    
12/A-9/XII/2.99/2015
```

I'm not doing anything yet, but i consider using `preg_match` to ensure the input contains some character. Here is my code:

```
preg_match("#[0-9A-Za-z./]#", $text);
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: that would match almost everything. do you need a specific string format? like '/' separated?

Comment: What are the rules for what should/shouldn't be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this based on your string:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}\/[a-zA-Z]-[0-9]\/[A-Z]+\/([0-9.]+\/)?[0-9]+$
```

It would match
`12/A-9/XII/2015`
and `12/A-9/XII/2.99/2015` but not `a12/A-9/XII/2.99/2015`, `12/A-9/XII/a2.99/2015` or `12/A-9/XII/2.99/2015a`

See it live and the explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/E3cTun/3)

Comment: it will match both of them. first entry has whitespaces on it

Comment: Unclear at this point if that is an exact copy or rough. Also lacking a lot of other information.

Comment: thanks for answer, it opend my mind a little to understand the pattern , sensei.  and i can modify it a bit by myself :D @rai